# Redis failed to optimize storage space from using string to hashmap

Tags: redis

When storing data in Redis,I changed the key-value pairs of user IDs and corresponding information from using the string structure to using the hashmap structure.I also confirmed that the underlying encoding format is ziplist.On average, each hashmap stores 50 data entries, with a string value size of 600 bytes. The size of each hashmap is approximately 28KB, and the total storage size is around 28MB. However,the storage sizes of both approaches are almost identical. Why?
[fig-1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ICyjd.png)
[fig-2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CRYok.png)
[fig-3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WP9PB.png)
Increase or decrease the storage quantity in the hashmap,but the storage space remains basically unchanged.